# Store object values into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've this piece of code, it retrieves a list of 'Client' where FULL_NAME like a KEY I input.

```js
[
  {
    id(pin):1
    full_name(pin):"James Marius Bolord"
    email(pin):"mariusjames32@gmail.com"
    phone(pin):"9832910293"
    dob(pin):"1981-05-05"
    location(pin):"REXDALE"
    user_id(pin):1
  },
  {
    id(pin):23
    full_name(pin):"Carl Barard"
    email(pin):"mariusjames32@gmail.com"
    phone(pin):"9832910293"
    dob(pin):"1981-05-05"
    location(pin):"REXDALE"
    user_id(pin):1
  },
  {
    id(pin):9
    full_name(pin):"Tony Falape"
    email(pin):"mariusjames32@gmail.com"
    phone(pin):"9832910293"
    dob(pin):"1981-05-05"
    location(pin):"REXDALE"
    user_id(pin):1
  }
]
```

Now I learn that you can make use of object by doing this:

```js
const zoo = {
  lion: '',
  panda: '',
};

Object.keys(zoo);
// ['lion', 'panda']

Object.values(zoo);
// ['', '']

Object.entries(zoo);
// [ ['lion', ''], ['panda', ''] ]
```

Until there, everything is fine on my mind. What I would like to do is having this type of result from that object:

```js
const full_name = [
    "James Marius Bolord",
    "Carl Barard",
    "Tony Falape",
   
  ];
```

So every time I type a key in, it should create an array of the full_name Key of the Client Table. I would appreciate the suggestion and ideas.

Comment: How do you arrive at the `full_name` array as you've shown? Those names in there do not match the names in your original data. Some names are truncated, and some are concatenated with others.

Comment: return Client::where('full_name', 'like', '%' . $full_name . '%')->get();

Comment: @Terry sorry, i saw that the second value doesn't have key "a". i was just giving an example.

Comment: What is the criteria for populating `full_name` array?

Comment: @chablis18 The problem is that `Bolord Tony` and `Falape Carl Barard` do not even exist in your original data.

Comment: @Nitheesh I am trying to do an autocomplete input with suggestions.

Comment: @Terry i Know. The last code was just an example of what i would like to have from my object data. I would like to make an array of FULL_NAME values that will come when i input anything

Comment: I edited the code now. You view now

Comment: Just use `inputArray.map(node => node['full_name(pin)'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the typo in your desired result, if all you want is to extract full names from your array of objects, then use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const full_name = data.map(entry => entry.full_name);
```

If you want to implement some kind of autocomplete/autosuggest feature, [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) is a very good candidate for your use-case:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    full_name: "James Marius Bolord",
    email: "mariusjames32@gmail.com",
    phone: "9832910293",
    dob: "1981-05-05",
    location: "REXDALE",
    user_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    full_name: "Carl Barard",
    email: "mariusjames32@gmail.com",
    phone: "9832910293",
    dob: "1981-05-05",
    location: "REXDALE",
    user_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    full_name: "Tony Falape",
    email: "mariusjames32@gmail.com",
    phone: "9832910293",
    dob: "1981-05-05",
    location: "REXDALE",
    user_id: 1
  }
];

const full_name = data.map(entry => entry.full_name);
console.log(full_name);

// Populate datalist as a UI/UX feature
const datalist = document.querySelector('#fullnames');
data.forEach(entry => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = entry.full_name;
  
  datalist.appendChild(option);
});
```

```html
<input list="fullnames" />
<datalist id="fullnames"></datalist>
```

Comment: Des this needs an answer? The question can be closed since this just needs `Array.map` no other things to be done

Comment: @Nitheesh Why this question does not need an answer? This is a proper answer. Whether the solution is small to just one line to n number of lines, in the end, it's an answer.

Comment: @Nitheesh User of your reputation would realize that a little help goes a long way. Mark it as duplicate if you wish, that's your choice. I'm sorry you can dish it but cannot take it. I was simply holding you up to the same standard you self-proclaim as the enforcer of it. ¯\\_ (ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Terry This question has already been cloed by a group of people including you. Even you closed with the tag "need deails or clarity" and you still ansered for a question that is not clear to you. So I dont need to do anyting with this question.

Comment: @Nitheesh I closed it because the original question has an output that was not consistent with the data: may I suggest you read the comments first? ;) you do you. Have a good day and bye.

Comment: @Terry The user made the output consistent. Then still why you didnt revert the close? I didnt see any issues with my downvote. Good Bye.